# How do I merge signals in Helm?

Tags: haskell, frp, elm

I am working on a project using [Helm](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/helm), which is based on the Elm language.

I need to trigger an event based on which signal out of a pair of signals arrives first. In Elm, I would use the [merge](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.0.1/Signal#merge) function, but I cannot find an equivalent in Helm. The closest I see is combine (in the signal library), which doesn't appear to do what I want. It seems that combine just takes a list of signals and makes them directly into a signal of lists, which is not quite what I'm looking for.

EDIT: specifically I am looking for a function with signature `Signal a -> Signal a -> Signal a` that takes the first signal to fire and discards the second.

What's the best way to accomplish this in Helm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way would be finding out how Helm's `Signal`s are implemented in terms of Elerea's stuff, and implementing `merge` in those more primitive terms. I'm afraid I can't help you there, because I don't know Helm well and I don't know Elerea at all.

I *can* help you with a hacky solution based solely on Helm. You can use `timestamp` to distinguish different events from zipped signals:

```
merge sigL sigR =
  let
    tsMerge (t1,v1) (t2,v2) =
        if t1 >= t2
          then v1
          else v2
  in
    tsMerge <~ timestamp sigL ~~ timestamp sigR
```

Comment: This ended up not working very well for some reason. It varied on different machines: I tried it on a linux computer and it worked fine, but when I tried it on a linux virtual box it made nothing happen at all. The way I fixed it was a hacky merge that basically took the signal I wanted to prevail each time with a `lift2`.

Comment: Strange that the behaviour differed per machine, that sounds like a bug to me...  
I don't understand how you'd make a `merge` with `lift2`, how did you do that?

Comment: I'm sure it's a bug. I had to present my project, though, on the virtualbox so had to make a work around. I think since the Helm people have tried a monoid implementation. Im sure that's also a bit buggy too. I think Im going to stick to Elm in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine things using the `Applicative` instance. For example `liftA2 (,)` will have type `Signal a -> Signal b -> Signal (a,b)`.

(I'm not 100% sure if this is your question, though. If your question is about merging events like `Event a -> Event a -> Event a`, I'm not sure helm has features like that. I can only find the documentation for behavior-like `Signal`s that have continuous semantics.)

Comment: Yes I am asking about merging events like `signal a -> signal a -> signal a`. Specifically I want the behavior to take the first signal that fires and discard the other. But, thank you, Ill upvote you once I have enough reputation.

Comment: Sure, sorry I couldn't be more helpful. In netwire it's http://hackage.haskell.org/package/netwire-5.0.1/docs/Control-Wire-Event.html#v:merge but I don't see anything similar in helm.